# Conditional IE8 stylesheet not loaded

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I'm having a problem getting my conditional IE8 and below stylesheet to work. I've placed the conditional statement below the regular stylesheet links but with no result.

This is my current setup:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all and (max-width: 640px)" href="/css/mobile-new.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all and (min-width:641px) and (max-width: 768px)" href="/css/tablet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all and (min-width:769px) and (max-width: 1024px)" href="/css/tablet-landscape.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all and (min-width:1025px)" href="style.css" />


<!--[if lte IE 8]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />   
<![endif]-->
```

As you can see it should use the regular 'desktop' stylesheet as media queries are not supported in IE8 and below. If I just place

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

in the head it works fine and the styles are also displayed in IE8 but I really need to seperate the stylesheets for the mobile/tablet versions.

I've already tried respond.js and css3-mediaqueries.js to skip the conditional stylsheet part but with no result.

Comment: How are you testing this – are you using a _real_ IE 8, or …?

Comment: Why don't you add all of the CSS into one file using media queries and then use something like `respond.js` to handle it on IE8?

Comment: @Cbroe not in a real IE8 browser but in IE11 within the document / legacy mode

Comment: @BeatAlex you really don't want to see the current separate stylesheets, that are huge and it would be a development nightmare to place it all in one even larger stylesheet.

Comment: When I use IE11 to emulate IE8 it doesn't work properly with stylesheets. Use a site like http://browserstack.com to test it.

Comment: @BeatAlex completely forgot about Browserstack and did a test there. It seems to be ok in IE8 now. Thanks.

Comment: No worries! IE11 does a poor job of emulating other browser versions.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: else,set the link for IE8 first, others shouldon't overwrite any way since IE8 it does not understand mediaquerie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Internet Explorer 11 trying to emulate Internet explorer 8, you will find that it does a very poor job of it.

Use a site like [Browserstack](http://browserstack.com) and you can run it from an actual computer running IE8 and then there, you should find that your code now works as it is supporting conditional statements, unlike IE11, which has dropped conditional statements.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try testing IE8 in Windows XP Mode, which is available through Windows Virtual PC.

This Virtual Machine is made by Windows, and comes with IE8, and has helped me personally for testing with IE8.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows7/install-and-use-windows-xp-mode-in-windows-7